# How do I create a DOM in function of an angular-js variable?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a function, `renderFOO(value)`, that returns a DOM element. How can I have that element rendered inside an AngularJS application, in function of a variable in a model?

I've managed to solve it using a directive:

```
<input type="range" ng-model="foo">
<foo></foo>

app.directive("foo", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link : function(scope, elem, attr){
            scope.$watch("foo",function(periodo){
                elem[0].innerHTML = "";
                elem[0].appendChild(renderFOO(foo));
            });
        }}
});
```

But I think that is big and probably not idiomatic and the solution would be something like:

```
<input type="range" ng-model="foo">
<div>{{renderFOO(foo)}}</div>
```

Which does not work.

Comment: Where is the `renderFOO` function? I mean is it scoped? Is it from another library?

Comment: what are you trying to do? mostley its not a very good idea to manipulate the DOM directly when using AngularJS

Comment: I'm rendering an SVG chart dynamically, so I created the `renderFOO` function which returns the chart as I need it.

Comment: @Viclib were you able to make any progress on this? Was my suggestion able to help you?

Comment: @scniro I've ran out of time for this issue for now, so I left it in a non optimal way. I will come back to this problem eventually, test your suggestion and give you a feedback. Thank you!

Comment: @Viclib cool np I'll be looking forward to hearing your findings :)

Comment: @Viclib any progress yet? I'd really appreciate it if we can close this issue out for you

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to leverage [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) in the [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) module - offering the ability to bind DOM elements to some value. Observe the following simplified example...

```
<button ng-click="renderFoo()">render</button>
<div ng-bind-html="foo"></div>
```

---

```
$scope.renderFoo = function() {
    $scope.foo = '<span class="example">stuff</span>'
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/61gtz5gv/) - simplified demo